# C# iTextSharp PdfCopy to MemoryStream copies entire document and single page

Tags: asp.net, itext

I am trying to make a one page PDF from a 3 page PDF document using memory stream.  But when the code below executes, all 3 pages get added and not just the first page.

What am I missing here?  Please help.
Note:  I am using iTextSharp v5.5.13

```
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser;
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
byte[] fileToBeEncrypted = null;
string sSourcePDF = "C:\\my3pageFile.pdf;
PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(sSourcePDF);

    Document document = new Document();
    PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(document, ms) {CloseStream = false};
    document.Open();
    copy.AddPage(copy.GetImportedPage(pdfReader, iPage));
    document.Close();
    fileToBeEncrypted = ms.ToArray();  //returns the ENTIRE DOCUMENT AND NOT JUST PAGE 1
```

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Tom

Comment: Please share the PDF in question.

Comment: What is `iPage`? Your original code doesn't have a loop that goes from 1 to 3 by any chance? That would explain the behavior you describe. In its current state, the only answer that can be given to your question is: **YOUR CODE DOESN'T COMPILE** because `iPage` isn't defined. If you want a better answer, **SHARE CODE THAT COMPILES!**

Comment: Also: please stop using old versions of iText. We abandoned the name iTextSharp about 2 years ago. We only release *maintenance updates* for iText 5 (created for paying customers who can't upgrade to iText 7). You should use iText 7. See [iText 7: Jump-Start Tutorial - .NET version](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial-net/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial-net-version) and [download iText 7](https://developers.itextpdf.com/itext7/download-and-install-information/NET). Why would you continue to use an old version that is no longer supported?

Comment: Sorry.  I was just giving the highlights.  iPage is an Integer and its value is 1.

Comment: My issue is, after the copy and close, I then set an array fileToBeEncrypted = ms.ToArray();  And when I convert the byte[] fileToBeEncrypted to a pdf, the pdf contains all 3 pages and not just page 1.  This is my issue.  And I can't seem to figure out how to create a single page PDF from a n page pdf source using itextSharp's v 5.5.13.

Comment: If you like I can send you the  entire code file.  But I was trying to limit it to just the area that I can't figure out.

Answer (score 1):

The above code pdfCopy.GetImportedPages does works and I found an error further down in my own code.